# デザイン崩れ: 問い合わせページで出るポップアップのタイトル

Tags: バグ, 完了, デザイン

URL: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact

問い合わせ内容をドロップダウンから選んだら出るポップアップ:

[image: popup]

タイトルの文字列と区切り線がくっついてしまっています。